# How to make MessageDialog Box in the center

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Hi This is the MessageDialog Box.

```
var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Search has been found.");
// Show the message dialog
await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

I have these questions:

1. How to make it the size I wanted. Example : appear in the center with Square Box size?
2. How to add a Title for this MessageBox Example : Movies
3. How to make it to take answer Yes, No or cancel
4. Can add background color?

Thanks

Comment: It is considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are your answers:

Num 1. You cannot make the MessageDialog any size you want, it sizes itself.

Num 2. A MessageDialog's title can be handled like this:

```
new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Content", "Title");
```

Num 3. Changing a messageDialog's buttons is like this:

```
var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Content", "Title");
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("yes", (s) => { /* TODO: */}));
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("no", (s) => { /* TODO: */}));
dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("cancel"));
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Num 4. You cannot change the MessageDialog background, it colors itself.

As an aside, there is a fully customizable dialog in Callisto that might be useful, but more work (perhaps you are paid by the hour :) ): https://github.com/timheuer/callisto

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842), `MessageDialog` will not work. You need to first create UI of your popup as `Usercontrol`, then set the child of popup as that user control. I have given the sample below. One more option is to use `InputDialog`, which is available in  [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/).

MyUserControl.xaml (Set apropriate height width to `<UserContol />`)

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="21*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="16*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="63*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Movies" FontSize="30" Margin="20,20,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Search has been found." FontSize="15" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,20,0,0"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Margin="20,0,0,0">
        <Button Content="Yes" />
        <Button Content="No" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Popup p = new Popup();
    p.Child = new MyUserControl();
    p.IsOpen = true;
    p.HorizontalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width - ((MyUserControl)(p.Child)).Width) / 2;
    p.VerticalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height - ((MyUserControl)(p.Child)).Height) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is truly a "modal" input/message for the app, don't try to change the UX design.  Dialogs in WinRT apps are supposed to be like MessageDialog.  If you divert from that - which is system wide -- you are changing a pattern that is consistent across the system, except for your app.

If what you want is more of a non-modal dialog, which sounds like you may want...you can use, as Jerry suggested, create your own based on Popup, or using a 3rd party toolkit like [Callisto](http://winrtxamltoolkit.com), which provides the Flyout base for you.

Comment: Pretty cool when the XAML team themselves answer your question!